# Change the way "add content" and "node's" are displayed

Tags: nodes, theming

I was wondering how one would go about changing the layout of the nodes when you are adding content, as well as when you view the full story.

I want certain text to be bigger, some fields to be placed side by side, some vertically. I want full control over the layout. I tried editing the CSS to change fonts and colors but it all changes fonts for the enitre website and not just in the node view. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`page--node--[content-type].tpl.php` = node template for a specific content type (no square brackets)

`page--node--add--[content-type].tpl.php` = node/add template for specific content type.

Copy/paste the code you have in node.tpl.php and **clear your server cache**. Now you can add custom classes everywhere or even create a custom HTML structure to render your fields. See the [node.tpl.php documentation](http://drupal.org/node/11816) and [Drupal 7 template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's strange. The docs say that the template for a node type should be `node--[content-type].tpl.php` and this works for me. However, `node--add--[content-type].tpl.php` doesn't work for me, and prefixing it with `page--` _does_ make it work (sort of, anyway -- drupal recognizes it as the template for the add content page for that type, but fails to display the page). Any idea about why it's inconsistent that way? UPDATE: never mind, it's because you can set a template for any page at all starting from the `page--` root. Anyway, thanks!