# Base tpl file for "add content" page?

Tags: theming

I'm building my first drupal site, and I'm aware there's a huge amount about theming that I don't understand. Right now I'm learning to create custom layouts for specific pages by copying and modifying the template file for that page type (e.g., `node.tpl.php` -> `node-—my-content-type.tpl.php`). Now I'm trying to modify the "add content" page for a specific content type. Is there a template file that I can copy and modify, and if so, where can I find it? Or does this page type need to be handled differently?

This is in Drupal 7.

*What I've tried:*

- Modifying `node.tpl.php` doesn't affect the add content page, nor does creating and modifying `node--add.tpl.php` nor `node--add--my-content-type.tpl.php`.
- Modifying `page.tpl.php` does affect the add content page (and all other pages). However...
- Copying it to `page--node--add--my-content-type.tpl.php` (as suggested in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22572/change-the-way-add-content-and-nodes-are-displayed)) causes the add content page for my-content-type to not display at all, so apparently there is some other template info that's needed.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer this module help what page suggestion should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
theme_node_add_list
```

Parameters

$variables: An associative array containing:

content: An array of content types.

```
function theme_node_add_list($variables) {
  $content = $variables['content'];
  $output = '';

  if ($content) {
    $output = '<dl class="node-type-list">';
    foreach ($content as $item) {
      $output .= '<dt>' . l($item['title'], $item['href'], $item['localized_options']) . '</dt>';
      $output .= '<dd>' . filter_xss_admin($item['description']) . '</dd>';
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';
  }
  else {
    $output = '<p>' . t('You have not created any content types yet. Go to the <a href="@create-content">content type creation page</a> to add a new content type.', array('@create-content' => url('admin/structure/types/add'))) . '</p>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

See [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/theme_node_add_list/7)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to modify or theme the node form page of all the node types then you can use:

page--node--add.tpl.php    = Add New Node
page--node--edit.tpl.php   = Edit Existing Node 
page--node--delete.tpl.php = Delete Node

Further reading here Template [(theme hook)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

If you need it to be specific like:

page--my-article-type--add.tpl.php then use theme suggestion function like something below:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
 global $theme_key;
 $theme_name = $theme_key;
 if (!empty($variables['node']) && !empty($variables['node']->type)) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $variables['node']->type;
 }
}
```